# Syntax error json response is not valid

Tags: json, syntax

I 'm meeting a problem with a JSON response :

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
...il.com","jpegPhoto":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQE
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

I don't know why this error occurs.
Any idea ?

Comment: can you post your JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "user": "Toto",
    "message": "Toto",
    "image" : "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASADDDDD"
}
```

I cut the value of "image" because it's too long ;)